How could langchain agent step by step in `astream_event()`?
Example Code
@tool
async def tool1():
    """tool1"""
    print('start1...')
    cmd = {
        'cmd': 'Scrape',
    }
    await asyncio.sleep(5) # do something need long time.
    go2_command_queue.put(cmd)
    print('time1....')


@tool
async def tool2():
    """tool2"""
    print('start2...')
    print(go2_command_queue.qsize())
    print('time2....')


async def agent_completion(
    agent_executor,
    message: str,
    tools: List = None,
) -> AsyncGenerator:
    """Base on query to decide the tool which should use.
    Response with `async` and `streaming`.
    """
    tool_names = [tool.name for tool in tools]


    async for event in agent_executor.astream_events(
        {
            "input": message,
            "tools": tools,
            "tool_names": tool_names,
            "agent_scratchpad": lambda x: format_to_openai_tool_messages(x["intermediate_steps"]),
        },
        version='v2'
    ):
        kind = event['event']
        if kind == "on_chain_start":
            if (
                event["name"] == "Agent"
            ):
                yield(
                    f"\n### Agent: `{event['name']}`，Agent Input: `{event['data'].get('input')}`\n"
                )
        elif kind == "on_chat_model_stream":
            content = event["data"]["chunk"].content
            if content:
                yield content
        elif kind == "on_tool_start":
            yield(
                f"\n### Tool: `{event['name']}`，Tool Input: `{event['data'].get('input')}`\n"
            )
        elif kind == "on_tool_end":
            yield(
                f"\n### Tool Finished: `{event['name']}`，Tool Results: \n"
            )
            yield(
                f"`{event['data'].get('output')}`\n"
            )
        elif kind == "on_chain_end":
            if (
                event["name"] == "Agent"
            ):
                yield(
                    f"\n### Agent Finished: `{event['name']}`，Agent Results: \n"
                )
                yield(
                    f"{event['data'].get('output')['output']}\n"
                )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    llm = ChatOpenAI(
        model='gpt-4o',
        temperature=0.,
        api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY,
        streaming=True,
        max_tokens=None,
    )
    tools = [
        too1,
        tool2,
        tool3,
        ...
    ]
    agent = create_openai_tools_agent(llm, tools, AGENT_PROMPT)
    agent_executor = AgentExecutor(
        agent=agent,
        tools=tools,
        verbose=False,
        return_intermediate_steps=True
    )

    while True:
        user_message = input('Query: ') # tool1 then tool2
        responses = agent_completion(agent_executor, user_message, tools)
        async for response in responses:
            print(response, flush=True)


Results
### Tool: `tool1`，Tool Input: `{}`

start1...
start2...
0
time2...

### Tool: `tool2`，Tool Input: `{}`

time1....

### Tool Finished: `tool1`，Tool Results: 

`None`


### Tool Finished: `tool2`，Tool Results: 

`None`

Description
If some of my tools have dependencies, for example: tool3 needs to wait for tool2 to complete before it can be executed. Is there a way to achieve this? Through astream_event, I noticed that different tools are executed almost concurrently in an asynchronous manner.
I also tried using the .stream method. Although this method can execute tools step by step, the task process is not output in a streaming manner, which is not what I want.

Did you find any luck here? I'm facing a similar issue. I'm trying to update my graph state after my tool 1 is executed, and I'm awaiting the updates [since I need these updates in my second function]. But instead, langgraph decides to skip the await and move to the next event regardless.

Not yet, the astream_event will almost trigger all the tool in the same time.

Try to add await inside loop?
        elif kind == "on_tool_start":
            yield(
                f"\n### Tool: `{event['name']}`，Tool Input: `{event['data'].get('input')}`\n"
            )
            await asyncio.sleep(3) # add this line?

